# PDO syntax error for SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a basic query which gets all fields and exports the file but it keeps giving me an error. My code looks like this:

```
$array = ['users'];

foreach($array AS $i){
        $file = $i.'.sql';

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ? INTO OUTFILE ?");
        try {
            $stmt->execute(array($i,$file));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $log .= $e -> getMessage().'........ \n ';
        }
}
```

I keep getting this error how ever:

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' INTO OUTFILE 'users.sql'' at line 1.`

What is the correct syntax for this ?

Comment: Try
 SELECT * INTO 'users.sql' FROM `users` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It(Syntax) should be the other way around

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ? FROM ?;
```

See the documentation [**`here`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html)

**EDIT :**

As [JAL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92448/jal) clarified, The table name cannot be passed as a parameter under a **`PreparedStatement`**. So your query should be like

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ? FROM users;
```

Comment: Hmm that  did seem to fix that issue but i got `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users'' at line 1` for some reason it does not like the table name

Comment: @Dave, See JAL's answer , that is the other part of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prepare a statement where the table name is a parameter.

See [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Comment: @Dave I recall running into this problem myself working with PDO long ago. It's nice to find an explanation.